# Usar la misma clase entre jframe Form

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Hola estoy creando una aplicacion java con netbeans, en ella tengo varios jframe Form, para distintas funciones de la aplicacion. En unos de ellos cree una clase para llenar un combobox con datos de una base de datos. Mi duda es como hago para utilizar esta misma clase en los otros Formularios. Perdon si no esta claro la consulta pero mis conocimientos de Java son basicos.

Copio la clase en cuestion:

```
   public void mostrarjardin() {
    try {
        Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select * from jardines");
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            cmb_jardin_id.addItem(rs.getString("jardin"));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error en cargar jardines." + e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡ERROR jardines!!, contacte al administrador.");
    }
}
```

dentro del mismo formulario la llamo directamente con

mostrarjardin();

Y con eso ya me llena el combobox

[image: Copio una imagen de la estructura de la aplicacion para tratar de ser mas claro]

Aca una imagen de la esctructura de la aplicacion.

Aca una imagen del formulario con el combobox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creaste una `clase` o un `método`? `mostrarjardin()` es un método. Después tenés alguna clase que engloba a todas las que van a usar el método `mostrarjardin()`? Si es así podrías crear un método `estatico` en esa clase global y llamarlo desde los distintos  jframe Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Antes que nada

```
public void mostrarjardin()
```

> es un método no una clase, las cases empiezan con public class nombre. 
>   Como lo veo yo, tenes un error de concepto, te recomiendo que averigües acerca del modelo vista controlador (MVC);
>   No obstante si queres seguir con tu modelo, lo que podes hacer es recibir un JComboBox como parametero e inicializar la clase donde tenes tu metodo. ejemplo:
>   Suponiendo que tenes dos clases ,clase1 (donde tenes tu metodo) y clase2 (otra clase de donde queres usar el metodo).

```
public class Clase1 extends JFrame{
//todos los objetos propios de tu GUI
public void mostrarJardin(JComboBox cmb_jardin_id ){
 try {
    Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select * from jardines");
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        cmb_jardin_id.addItem(rs.getString("jardin"));
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("Error en cargar jardines." + e);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡ERROR jardines!!, contacte al administrador.");
}
}
}
```

> Para usarlo desde Clase1 seria

```
mostrarJardin(mcmb_jardin_id);
```

> Para usarlo desde Clase2 seria

```
public class Clase2 extends JFrame{
//Objetos propios de la GUI
JComboBox comboBoxDeTuClase = new JComboBox(); 
Clase1 cl1= new Clase1();
cl1.mostrarJardin(comboBoxDeTuClase);
}
```

> Con eso debería funcionar, pero una vez mas te recomiendo que averigües acerca de MCV, ya que donde crezca un poco tu programa va a ser muy difícil modificarlo o expandirlo.

Comment: Gracias Sergio, voy a leer sobre el tema y probar lo que me propones.